# iterator for 2d vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

How to create iterator/s for 2d vector (a vector of vectors)?

Comment: May-be describe the context of the question a bit better?

Comment: More specifically: what is the declaration of your 2d vector? What order do you want to iterate? How do you want to use the iterator?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Although your question is *not* very clear, I'm going to assume you mean a 2D vector to mean a vector of vectors:

```
vector< vector<int> > vvi;
```

Then you need to use two iterators to traverse it, the first the iterator of the "rows", the second the iterators of the "columns" in that "row":

```
//assuming you have a "2D" vector vvi (vector of vector of int's)
vector< vector<int> >::iterator row;
vector<int>::iterator col;
for (row = vvi.begin(); row != vvi.end(); row++) {
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        // do stuff ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that my question wasn't so clear but this is exactly what I wanted. Although I'm getting compiler error with this code:

cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' to 'int' on for (row = vvi.begin(); row != vvi.end(); row++) {

Comment: always use pre increment operators.  With vectors it's likely that it wont matter when using a vector but it's a bad habit to get into.  Life would be much clearer if it had been ++C instead of C++.

Comment: If there are only 2 elements in the columns. How to access them once we iterate through row.

Comment: @Anoop Sorry, I don't understand your question? Do you mean you need to access `*col[0]` and `*col[1]`?

Answer (score 16):

You can use range for statement to iterate all the elements in a two-dimensional vector.

```
vector< vector<int> > vec;
```

And let's presume you have already push_back a lot of elements into vec;

```
for(auto& row:vec){
   for(auto& col:row){
      //do something using the element col
   }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Another way to interpret this question is that you want a 1D iterator over a `vector<vector<>>` for example to feed it to `for_each()` or some other algorithm.

You can do that like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// An iterator over a vector of vectors.
template<typename T>
class vv_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>{
public:

  static vv_iterator<T> begin(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& vv) {
    return vv_iterator(&vv, 0, 0);
  }
  static vv_iterator<T> end(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& vv) {
    return vv_iterator(&vv, vv.size(), 0);
  }

  vv_iterator() = default;
  // ++prefix operator
  vv_iterator& operator++()
  {
    // If we haven't reached the end of this sub-vector.
    if (idxInner + 1 < (*vv)[idxOuter].size())
    {
      // Go to the next element.
      ++idxInner;
    }
    else
    {
      // Otherwise skip to the next sub-vector, and keep skipping over empty
      // ones until we reach a non-empty one or the end.
      do
      {
        ++idxOuter;
      } while (idxOuter < (*vv).size() && (*vv)[idxOuter].empty());

      // Go to the start of this vector.
      idxInner = 0;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  // --prefix operator
  vv_iterator& operator--()
  {
    // If we haven't reached the start of this sub-vector.
    if (idxInner > 0)
    {
      // Go to the previous element.
      --idxInner;
    }
    else
    {
      // Otherwise skip to the previous sub-vector, and keep skipping over empty
      // ones until we reach a non-empty one.
      do
      {
        --idxOuter;
      } while ((*vv)[idxOuter].empty());

      // Go to the end of this vector.
      idxInner = (*vv)[idxOuter].size() - 1;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  // postfix++ operator
  vv_iterator operator++(int)
  {
    T retval = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return retval;
  }
  // postfix-- operator
  vv_iterator operator--(int)
  {
    T retval = *this;
    --(*this);
    return retval;
  }
  bool operator==(const vv_iterator& other) const
  {
    return other.vv == vv && other.idxOuter == idxOuter && other.idxInner == idxInner;
  }
  bool operator!=(const vv_iterator &other) const
  {
    return !(*this == other);
  }
  const T& operator*() const
  {
    return *this;
  }
  T& operator*()
  {
    return (*vv)[idxOuter][idxInner];
  }
  const T& operator->() const
  {
    return *this;
  }
  T& operator->()
  {
    return *this;
  }

private:
  vv_iterator(std::vector<std::vector<T>>* _vv,
              std::size_t _idxOuter,
              std::size_t _idxInner)
    : vv(_vv), idxOuter(_idxOuter), idxInner(_idxInner) {}

  std::vector<std::vector<int>>* vv = nullptr;
  std::size_t idxOuter = 0;
  std::size_t idxInner = 0;
};



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {{3, 5, 2, 6}, {-1, -4, -3, -5}, {100}, {-100}};
    std::reverse(vv_iterator<int>::begin(a), vv_iterator<int>::end(a));
    for (const auto& v : a)
    {
        std::cout << "{ ";
        for (auto i : v)
           std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
{ -100 100 -5 -3 }
{ -4 -1 6 2 }
{ 5 }
{ 3 }
```

Note this won't work with `std::sort()` because that requires a random access iterator. You could make it a random access iterator but you'd have to scan the vector at the start so you can map from flat index to `idxOuter` and `idxInner` in constant time. Not totally trivial but not hard either.

Comment: I was looking for exactly your interpretation of the question. Am I right, that this is only the non-const iterator and one would need to write a second class for the `const_iterator`? Is there any specific reason you store indices instead of the vector iterators? Btw it took me a while to understand the example, because the output uses the "normal" iterators, while the usage of the 1D iterator is a bit hidden in this innocent looking `reverse` line.

Comment: Yes, in my actual code I have a `const_iterator` version. It's more or less a copy/paste with the non-const members removed (I couldn't find a way to avoid the copy/paste). Good point I guess there isn't a reason not to use vector iterators. That is probably better I just didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a vector like this:-
    `vector <vector<int>> vect{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};`
Now to use iterators with 2D vectors :-

```
 for(auto i = vect.begin() ; i<vect.end() ; i++)
  {
     for(auto j = i->begin() ; j<i->end() ; j++)
        cout << *j <<" ";
     cout <<"\n";  
     //similarly you can do other things
  }
```

Also other shorter way is

```
 for(auto i : vect)
  {
     for(auto j : i)
        cout << j <<" ";
     cout << "\n";
//similarly you can do other things also.
  }
```

Please note the way of calling variables is different in both the cases.

Comment: man, thanks for simplifying life.

Answer (score 1):

You can use auto keyword for such cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    vector<vector<int>>v;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        vector<int> x={1,2,3,4,5};
        v.push_back(x);
    }
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Print without iterator"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        vector<int> y=v[i];
        for(int j=0;j<y.size();j++)
        {
            cout<<y[j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Print with iterator"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for(auto iterator=v.begin();iterator!=v.end();iterator++)
    {
        vector<int> y=*iterator;
        for(auto itr=y.begin();itr!=y.end();itr++)
        {
            cout<<*itr<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's 2020, I'll post an updated and easy method. Works for c++11 and above as of writing.
See the following example, where elements (here: **tuples** of **<string, size_t>**) of 2D vector (vector of vector) is iterated to compare with another value (**string query**) and the function then returns first element with match, or indicate "Not found".

```
tuple<string, size_t> find_serial_data( vector <vector <tuple <string, size_t>>> &serial,
                                        string query)
{
    for (auto& i : serial)
    {
        for (auto& j : i)
        {
            if ( get<0>(j).compare(query) == 0) return j;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n Not found";
    return make_tuple( "", 0);
}
```

> Here is one example without the tuple thing:

```
string find_serial_data( vector <vector <string> > &serials,
                                        string query)
{
    for (auto& i : serials)
    {
        for (auto& j : i)
        {
            if ( j.compare(query) == 0) return j;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n Not found";
    return  "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean an STL iterator, and a custom container that implements a generic 2D array of objects, this is impossible.  STL iterators support only increment and decrement (i.e. "next" an "previous") operations, where motion through a 2D set requires four such primitives (e.g. left/right/up/down, etc...).  The metaphors don't match.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a vector of vectors, and you have `std::vector` in mind, there's no built in way to do it, as iterators only support increment and decrement operations to move forward and backwards.

A 2D vector is a matrix, and so you'd need two iterator types: a row iterator and a column iterator.  Row iterators would move "up" and "down" the matrix, whereas column iterators would move "left" and "right".

You have to implement these iterator classes yourself, which is not necessarily a trivial thing to do.  Unless, of course, you simply want to iterate over each slot in the matrix, in which case a double for loop using index variables `i` and `j` will work just fine.  Depending on your needs (your post is a bit lacking in content here), you may want to use `boost::numeric::ublas::matrix`, which is a matrix class from the Boost linear algebra library.  This matrix class has built-in row and column iterators, which make it generally easy to iterate over a matrix.

Comment: Exactly what I meant, 2D vector matrix with (now I know that two) iterators. I thought questions was clear :( ... anyway I'm quite new to vectors and I have to use them in this work.

Now another problem is that error I posted in above comment (formating is shit). Can't assign value to first (row) iterator as because that type mismatch.