# C++ vector of vectors in class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a class in which vectors of doubles are stored like this this:

```
class clsHalfphoneUnitJoinFeatures : public CBaseStructure
{
private:
    vector<double> m_content;
protected:
    virtual void ProcessTxtLine(string line);
public:
    vector<double> &Content();
    void Add(vector<double> &jf);
};
```

However, when I want to add a new vector of doubles, it won't work:

```
void clsHalfphoneUnitJoinFeatures::ProcessTxtLine(string line)
{
    line = CompactLine(line);
    if (line == "")
        return;

    int b = 0;
    int n = line.find("\t");
    string s = "";
    int idx = 0;
    vector<double>jf;
    jf.resize(16);
    int i = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        if (n == -1)//if this is the last item in this line
        {
            s = line.substr(b,line.length()-b);
            jf[i++] = atof(s.c_str());
            break;
        }
        s = line.substr(b,n-b);
        jf[i++] = atof(s.c_str());      
        b = n+1;
        n = line.find("\t",b);
    }
    m_content.push_back(jf);
}
```

The error I am getting is in

```
m_content.push_back(jf);
```

> error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)': Conversion of parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' in 'double &&' not possible

Can somebody tell me where I went wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jf` and `m_content` have the same type, you can't push `jf` as an element of `m_content`.

Try change

```
m_content.push_back(jf);
```

To:

```
m_content = jf;
```

If you want to have a **vector of vector of double type**, you need to declare `m_content` as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > m_content;
```

Comment: But I wanted to access the individual vectors using for example  ->Content[100]. If I say m_content = jf, I would not have several vectors in my class, but only 1.

Comment: @tmighty right, but the point is that your class is defined to have a single vector. So you have to change that, as suggested here.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am not sure how I can make it a vector of vectors.

Comment: @tmighty `std::vector<std::vector<double> > m_content;` is a vector of vectors...

Answer (score 0):

a) Error `m_content.push_back(jf);`. You are trying to push vector to a vector which can store double. so the compiler is giving error.

You can resolve it by assigning jf to m_context

```
m_content = jf;
```

b) Else if your implementation needs vector of vector follow the steps below

Declare m_content as vector of double vector.

```
vector<vector<double>> m_content;
 ...
 m_content.push_back(jf);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am now facing the problem that my code code does not work anymore:  vector<double>::iterator it = nHPJoinFeatures.Content().begin();
 for (;it != nHPJoinFeatures.Content().end(); ++it) Can you suggest how to do that now with my changed code?

Comment: What changes you made added recently?

Comment: I chose your approach vector<<vector<double>> m_content;

Comment: You have to understand how to iterate vector of vector.Refer following example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784573/iterator-for-2d-vector