# Displaying contents of 2D iterator C++11

Tags: c++11, iterator

I have been looking at this: [Iterator for 2d vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784573/iterator-for-2d-vector)

And wanted to ask whether or not it is possible to display the contents of a 2D iterator:

```
template<typename Inverse>
MFCC(Inverse begin, Inverse end, Struct::returnType type)
{   
  for(auto row = begin; (row != end); row++)
  {
      for(auto col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {


      }
  }
}
```

I have (studidly) tried the following:

`std::cout << *row*col << endl;`

But with no joy, I'm sure it's hitting me right in the face, but I just wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
template<typename Inverse>
void MFCC(Inverse begin, Inverse end)
{   
  for(auto row = begin; (row != end); row++)
  {
      for(auto col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        std::cout<<*col<<" ";
      }
      std::cout<<std::endl;
  }
}


//MFCC(vec.begin(),vec.end());
```

Not sure what is `Struct::returnType` , you probably can work around.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! But, why just `*col` tho? Also `Struct::returnType` is just an `enum` to determine whether or not the data should be stored as an `array` or `vector` but this is great!

Comment: @Phorce thanks, well you have a vector of vectors, using `*col` only you can access the elements.

Comment: That makes sense now, I am stupid sometimes! Accepted your answer