# dynamic 2-dimensional array with varying column size which is not known in advance

Tags: c++, arrays

I am a beginner in C++ programming. I want to construct a dynamic 2D array with varying column size which is not known in advance.

For example, from an array A[9]={1,2,3,0,4,0,1,2,1}.
Each time an element with value = 0 is encountered, a new row is created. Basically when a 0 is encountered, row value is increased and column value is reset to 0. If a non-zero value is encountered, the row value is maintained and column value is increased. I want to also find out the row and column size for the 2D array. I also want to be able to store the column and row value in other variables.
Based on above example, my desired 2D array should look as follows.

```
1 2 3
0 4
0 1 2 1
```

The following is the program that I am working on. I don’t know how to relate the change of row and column values with my 2D array.

```
    int nRows = 0;
    int **X = new int *[nRows];
    int *S  = new int  [nRows];
    int nCols=-1;

    int array[9]={1,2,3,0,4,0,1,2,1};

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {if (array[i]==0)
        {nRows++; 
        nCols=0;}
     else
        nCols++;}

    for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++)
    {     
     X[i] = new int[nCols];
     S[i] = nCols;
     cout<<"\n"<<S[i];}
```

I have searched other related questions but to my understanding, all of them assign the column size for each row themselves instead of depending on other formulations. Please excuse my English and let me know if I could clarify my question.Thanks.

Comment: "I want to construct a dynamic 2D array with varying column size which is not known in advance." - here you are: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working good:

```
int givenArray[9]={1,2,3,0,4,0,1,2,1};

vector<vector<int>> my2dArray;

for(int i=0;i<9;i++)  //iterate through all elements of the given array
{
if (i==0)  //adding the first element
    {
    my2dArray.resize(my2dArray.size()+1);
    my2dArray.back().push_back(givenArray[i]);
    continue;
    }
if (givenArray[i] == 0)   //re-size if 0 is encountered
    {
    my2dArray.resize(my2dArray.size()+1); 
    }
my2dArray.back().push_back(givenArray[i]);
}
```

For printing the output in 2d manner :

```
for (auto vec1d : my2dArray){
    {
        for (auto i : vec1d){
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, the upper part works fine. but I got the following message:                                                                  error: 'vec1d' does not name a type   
did I miss anything?

Comment: You will get that error if you are not using C++11. So, instead of the "auto" keyword, use iterators to print the elements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784573/iterator-for-2d-vector if you need help in that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
typedef std::vector<int> Row;
typedef std::vector<Row> TwoDArray;

TwoDArray arr;

int array[9]={1,2,3,0,4,0,1,2,1};

Row row;
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
   if (array[i]==0)
   {
      arr.push_back(row);
      row.clear();
      row.push_back(0);
   }
   else
   {
      row.push_back(array[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still not familiar with vector and currently studying it. I will try to implement vector in my problem solving.

Comment: I strongly suggest getting into the habit of using a proper matrix class like `boost::multi_array` instead of N-dimensional vectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[9]={1,2,3,0,4,0,1,2,1};
vector<vector<int>> result;

for(int i=0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); ++i)
{
    if (array[i] == 0 || i == 0)
        result.resize(result.size()+1);
    result.back().push_back(array[i]);
}
```