# How do you make a list of 2-D vectors without creating each differently?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a bunch of (12) 15x15 vectors and I would like to have them all in a list or something like that that will allow me to easily access one of the vectors and edit them, as well as be able to have a number assigned to each vector to easily tell them apart. While I know I could make 12 vectors with their own names, I would like to know how I could do this in a less intensive way.

I have the dimensions and the number of the vectors in constant ints in a header file, and preferably I would like to use these as well, but this is not necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterator for 2d vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784573/iterator-for-2d-vector)

Comment: If you want them named then a `map<string, vector<vector<int>>>` might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a vector of vector of vectors of integers.
I use it all the time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(15,1);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1(15,v);
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> vec(12,v1);

    auto i = vec[2][2];
    std::cout << i[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If size of dimensions are compile time constant, in order to keep stack tiny use vector for the top ranked dimension and array for the others:

```
using vec2d=std::array<std::array<int,15>,15>;
using vec3d=std::vector<vec2d>;    
vec3d v1;
v1.resize(12);
```