# Making a class iterable with iteration order depending on class implementation

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, polymorphism

I have a type that has two different implementations, using different data structures. One stores its data in a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>>`, the other in a 2D array `Data***`.

The elements are stored in a specific order, meaning that their position in the vector or 2D array matters. As such, when wanting to iterate over all data in my class, my for loops are dependent on the implementation, being basically one of the following:

```
for(auto& data : myClass->dataVector) { do Stuff }
for(int x = 0; x < myClass->xVals; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < myClass->yVals; y++ {
        do Stuff with myClass->dataArr[x][y]
    }
}
```

Since the two version of my class share similarities, I want to have a proper parent class that is implemented by two inheriting classes, hopefully in a way that I can iterate over my data by simply doing something such as:

```
for(auto& data : myClass) { doStuff }
```

(notice how myClass acts as if it was a collection itself, even if it actually is just a container of a collection)

where the way and order in which this iteration works obviously depends on the implementation of the class.

How do make my class iterable in such a manner?

Comment: Do you have two separate classes `class A { std::vector<...> dataVector; }; ` and `class B { int xVals; int yVals; Data** dataArr; };` or a single class containing all the fields?

Comment: someone did an iterator over a vector of vector here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48343634/1766544 Your iterator will be similar and derived from std::iterator

Comment: @Mestkon At the moment I have a single class containing all fields because I've just been hacking things together, but ultimately I want to have a parent class A and two implementations B and C.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Ill take a look, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have a base with all the data, and two derived classes with traversal behavior:

```
class Base {
public:
    std::vector<...> dataVector;
    int xVals;
    int yVals;
    Data** dataArr;
};
```

Defining `.begin()` and `.end()` makes a class iterable with `for_each`. A simple forwarding to the vector iterators is enough for the first case:

```
class DerivedA : private Base {
public:
    auto begin() { return this->dataVector.begin(); }
    auto begin() const { return this->dataVector.begin(); }
    auto end() { return this->dataVector.end(); }
    auto end() const { return this->dataVector.end(); }
}
```

For the `Data**` case you will have to define a custom iterator:

```
class iterator {
public:
    using value_type = Data;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference = Data&;
    using pointer = Data*;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    iterator() : m_base(), m_idx(0) { }
    iterator(Base* b, std::size_t idx) : m_base(b), m_idx(idx) { }
    
    reference operator*() const { return m_base->dataArr[m_idx / m_base->yVals][m_idx % m_base->y_vals]; }
    pointer operator->() const { return &**this; }

    friend iterator& operator++(iterator& rhs) { ++rhs.m_idx; return rhs; }
    friend iterator operator++(iterator& lhs, int) { auto cp = lhs; ++lhs; return cp; }

    friend bool operator==(iterator lhs, iterator rhs) { return lhs.m_idx == rhs.m_idx; }
    friend bool operator!=(iterator lhs, iterator rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }

private:
    Base* m_base;
    std::size_t m_idx;
};

class const_iterator { 
    // equivalent but const. (reference = const Data& and pointer = const Data*)
    // Make sure iterator is convertible to const_iterator.
};

class DerivedB : private Base {
    iterator begin() { return { this, 0 }; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return { this, 0 }; }
    iterator end() { return { this, this->xVals*this->yVals }; }
    const_iterator end() const { return { this, this->xVals*this->yVals }; }
};
```

Comment: Interesting. How come that neither of the three classes have to derive from some sort of iterator class? Does the compiler just check for the existence of .begin() and .end()? If so, wouldn't it be better to define begin and end in the Base class - and impl + the underlying structures in the derived classes? Also how come the iterator class you defined does not have to, for example, extend std::iterator? Same with const_iterator. It's also the first time I've seen the `using` keyword used like this. I assume the dereferencing iterator here plays the role of a ".next()" function, right?

Comment: There is no need to derive from anything to make an iterator. The requirements are listed here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator for different iterator concepts. The compiler just checks for .begin() and .end(), that's correct. The iterators have different types in the 2 cases, so it is impossible to define begin and end in the base class. It might be better to just have a single class and then have functions which returns iterable views of the data.

Comment: The iterator itself doesn't really have a different type though - in both cases it'll be a `Data*` (or `std::unique_ptr<Data>`). Also, what's the use of having both a const_iterator and iterator?

Comment: Also, in the current form the "next" function (iterator dereferencing) is defined in the iterator, not in the derived class. Is there a way to make the class itself an iterator in some sort? The dereferencing functionality, after all, is pretty much the only difference between the two classes, so it would feel really overblown to write two separate iterator classes for that

Comment: The iterator types are the custom `iterator` class or the `std::vector<...>::iterator` NOT `Data*`. You could implement the `iterator` class as a template and therefore not require a separate `const_iterator` class and instead instantiate with different template parameters to get the same result. It sounds like you should learn more about the c++ iterator concept which is a too large topic for me to explain in the comment section here.